# SQL Server connection arbitrarily returns 233 or 18456 error codes

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

While trying to test an invalid connection string against a SQL Server 2008 Express instance, I found this weird behavior: specifying an invalid `Initial Catalog` raises an `SQLException` whose Number is sometimes 233, and sometimes 18456.

Code may illustrate it better.

```
// The following connection string has a purposely incorrect initial catalog:
string invalidConnString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=INVALID_DATABASE_NAME;User Id=dummyUser;Password=dummyPassw;";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(invalidConnString);

try
{
    connection.Open();
}
catch (SqlException sex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sex.Number); // I "randomly" get either 233 or 18456
    throw;
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

The [system error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603.aspx) from the Books Online specify that

- **233** - A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
- **18456** - Login failed for user '%.*ls'.%.*ls

I presume both are different ways to say: *unsuccessful login*. But then, why isn't the failure consistent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Humberto,

This is a very common problem in using SQL Express and the root cause is AUTO_CLOSE database option is turned on by default for SQL Express. When all the users of the database close, the database is closed and shutdown cleanly. When users login next time, the permissions of the users for that database can't be verified quickly if the database is re-opening.

AUTO_CLOSE has other side effects also that it flushes the procedure cache and it could lead to higher cpu costs in general.

The be low command is your friend.

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx

Comment: Very nice! I'll accept your answer even though I'm not involved with that original project anymore. Thanks!